# how can i use common-node with mongo-sync in my nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, synchronization

i found the plugin [mongo-sync](https://github.com/olegp/mongo-sync) which can make me to use mongoDB synchronized

on the git,there show :

> It is a thin wrapper around the official MongoDB driver for Node. Here is a quick usage example that you can use with Common Node:

```
var Server = require("mongo-sync").Server;
var server = new Server('127.0.0.1');
var result = server.db("test").getCollection("posts").find().toArray();
console.log(result);
server.close();
```

how can i use like this?

it's mentioned that `use with Common Node`

whether it's means [common-node](https://github.com/olegp/common-node)?

so, how can i use it ? or use [mongo-sync](https://github.com/olegp/mongo-sync) straightforwardly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means you have to follow Common-Node [installation instructions](https://github.com/olegp/common-node#installation) and use `common-node` command instead of the plain-old `node` to run your program.

As the docs mention, to use it with plain-old `node` you need to use [node-fibers](https://github.com/laverdet/node-fibers) and make queries inside a `Fiber`.

No way around node-fibers I'm afraid, as mongo-sync is just a "synchronous" wrapper around asynchronous mongo driver, and it's hard to make async js code synchronous without some low level monkey-patching.

Comment: so,mongo-sync and node-fibers just make the code pretty when we coding on mongodb ?

Comment: @Shura they make code pretty in general. mongo-sync uses them to make mongo code prettier.

Comment: but i wouldn't wanna just pretty,i just want what they show in the example T-T

Comment: @Shura the code you posted *is* the example. You just have to run it with `common-node`.

Comment: i saw the readme,it's meas to use common-node in command ?like : common-node file.js. whether need to install something such as nodejs?

Comment: i found that:`[sudo] npm -g install common-node`, so ,it must running by use `common-node xxx.js`? does it can be used by other which is running by use `node xxxx.js`?

Comment: yes you need to install node-common (or node-fibers). Then you must run it using `common-node`, or inside a fiber from node-fibers using the plain `node`.